# Re-initiating the discussion with a seemingly busy Professor

Tags: professorship, email, projects

A couple of weeks back, I reached out to a Professor stating my interest in a project he had put up on his website. The professor was impressed with my resume and gave a brief description of his project.

He had also asked me a few questions about my skills/familiarity with languages and platforms. He also remarked that he is preparing to give a short test to decide where I stand in the project.

Unfortunately, the Professor has not got back to my reply. I had informed him that I was quite familiar with tools/skills needed for the project. It has been two weeks since he has replied(although I hear it is the exam session which may be keeping him busy).

Should I consider that the offer is null and void as he has stopped replying to mails for the last fortnight?

If I am to mail him now, shall I explain the literature survey undertaken during this period and what skills have been learnt?

Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, professors are busy. They need to do research and teach. They need to write and then publish papers and handle all matters related to teaching (prepare for course materials, exams, grading exams,... etc). So, two weeks not relying the e-mail sounds normal to me.

As in you case,

> *He also remarked that he is preparing to give a short test to decide where I stand in the project.*

and

> *I had informed him that I was quite familiar with tools/skills needed for the project.*

sound like you are ready for the test to convince him that you are qualified to join his project.

I would suggest you to send him an e-mail to tell him that you are ready for the test and asking what is the most convenient time for him to conduct it.

Surely, you can tell him the literature survey undertaken during this period. I am not sure about mentioning skills have been learnt during the two weeks period. To me, any skill that can be learnt in two weeks is not worth mentioning.

Good Luck !

Comment: ,It iis basically going to be a summer project and he had asked me about my plans of leaving the job. As I am going to resign, should I ask him if pre-poning my resignation would help in the project?

Comment: @envy_intelligence The current question is about re-initiating the discussion with a seemingly busy Professor. Your comment sounds like another question. Do you expect this summer job would become a permanent one eventually? If so, you probably want to ask another question.

Comment: Take this step by step.  Set up the test.  See how things go.  Don't talk about pre-poning your resignation.  Also, don't burn your bridges in your current job.  Wait until you have some kind of commitment from this guy before you get to that level of detail.